# Does URE apply in non-RAID setups?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hard-drive-failure

According to this article (http://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/) if you have a RAID 5 setup and one of your drives decides to die you would replace the dead one with a new one and try to rebuild but statically speaking based on the unrecoverable read error rate\URE you will more than likely run into a bad sector which will cause your rebuild to fail and some data will become unrecoverable.

But if this is true doesn't that mean that even if the hard drives were not run in RAID and one drive failed then statically speaking one of the remaining drive has a bad sector at this point and also have some unrecoverable data?

Does that mean URE should also be a consideration in non-RAID setups?

Comment: Of course does URE apply to non-RAID setups, and it should be considered. But the correlation between one disk failing and another disk having a relevant URE at the same point in time, obviously, only applies to RAID setups. Because in the RAID, the disk which fails in this scenario compensated the other disk's problem previously. -- I'm not sure why the linked article doesn't mention Data Scrubbing.

Comment: @ClassStacker - So at the current hard disk sizes and the current URE rates we will almost definitely get a bad sector if you say have 3 hard drive and decide to fill them up completely and do a complete read?

Comment: No. How did you come to that conclusion?